# Postman: How to delete/clear postman environment variable at run-time

Tags: postman

Is there any way to delete/clear postman environment variable using functions at runtime.
I could possibly set to blank or some special value but is there a general way of doing things.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sandbox API `pm.environment.unset(variableName)` also allows to do that.

In case is you want to clear all environment variables at once - you might want to do: `pm.environment.clear()`.

This will clear all your environment values.

Refer: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmenvironment

Comment: This is a better answer so accepting this over the one I provided.

Comment: sidenote: `pm.globals.clear();` will clear all global variables

Comment: Just to clarify, `pm.environment.clear()` will not just clear the environment values, but all the variables too. This is not the same as running `unset` on all environment variables (which just clears environment values)

Answer (score 24):

Ok - so this does it.

```
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("key");
```

Comment: `postman.clearEnvironmentVariables()` would remove all the environment variables at once.

Answer (score 1):

And the right one syntax is:

```
pm.environment.unset("key");
```

Comment: That is what is also mentioned in the answer. Also, this is not the RIGHT syntax but one of the right answers. This is a pm api but postman also provides its own wrapper `clearEnvironmentVariable`

Answer (score 1):

I'v also come across this possible solution for setting the variables to blank:
https://community.postman.com/t/can-i-clear-just-the-current-values-in-an-environment/6176

I have found that using the `pm.environment.clear()` or `pm.environment.unset(variableName)` deletes the variable from the environment. But sometimes I want to keep the variable and just clear the value, e.g. I want to share the environment with someone else but it contains values which should only apply to myself (such as oauth credentials).

So I re-used the function described in the link and use a `pm.environment.set(variableName, "")` instead of an unset.

So my function looks like:

```
function clearVariables() {
    // Get all the names of our env variables and put them in an array
    const environmentVariables = pm.environment.values.map(function(variable) {
        return variable.key;
    });

    // Filter through the above array but don't add variables as per conditions    
    const binTheseVariablesOff = environmentVariables.filter(function(variable) {        
        return !variable.toLowerCase().includes("auth");
    });

    // Now go through this new array and clear these env variables
    return binTheseVariablesOff.forEach(function(variableName) {        
        pm.environment.set(variableName, "");
    });
}

// Call the function
clearVariables();
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking to clear the global variable :

I was accessing a timing varibale through

```
pm.globals.get("timings")
```

and I was able to clear it by running

```
pm.globals.unset("timings")
```

in the "Tests" section [image]