# postman dynamic unset environment variables

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Is there a way to unset environment variables dynamically?
I would like to access the environment vars and do a find & replace/delete action so I can test more dynamically.

For instance, say I want to test the creation of users, I create vars like {{tmp-username}}, {{tmp-email}}, etc... replace them with other values for the next test and remove them when I'm done.

I would do a stringsearch on tmp- if I knew how to access these using code...

Thanks in advance for any reply

To clarify, this question is different: [Postman: How to delete/clear postman environment variable at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246721/postman-how-to-delete-clear-postman-environment-variable-at-run-time)
This deals with knowing the exact name of the var you wish to unset. I want to search or iterate trough the vars to remove or edit them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postman: How to delete/clear postman environment variable at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246721/postman-how-to-delete-clear-postman-environment-variable-at-run-time)

Comment: Could you not just use a data file and the collection runner to do this?

Comment: @Danny Dainton I'd like to avoid separate files as we can then share collections & environments without the need of sharing data files as well. There's also a security issue to share these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a function in the `Tests` tab to iterate through the variables and clear them out after the last test had run?

For example:

```
function cleanup() {
    const clean = _.keys(pm.environment.toObject())
    _.each(clean, (arrItem) => {
        pm.environment.unset(arrItem)
    })
}
cleanup()
```

This wouldn't 'replace' the values but this would give you confidence that the ones that are set during the run are not being used again.

**EDIT**

If you wanted to clear out a specific set of variables, ones that you have given a certain prefix, you could use this:

```
function cleanup() {
    const clean = _.keys(pm.environment.toObject())
    _.each(clean, (arrItem) => {
        if (arrItem.startsWith("tmp")) {
            pm.environment.unset(arrItem)
        }
    })
}
cleanup()
```

If you want to see all the keys and the values you could use this to log them to the console:

```
_.map(pm.environment.toObject(), (value, key) => console.log(`The key is '${key}' and the value is '${value}'`))
```

Comment: While this is definitely an interesting script, it uses the exact variable names. I was hoping to access the environment vars more dynamically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? - It seems like you're just waiting for an answer to be presented. Maybe try and create the `clean` array values by using the `keys` from the `pm.environment.toObject()` function.

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should now be more dynamic and based on the variables that have been set.

Comment: Excellent! That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know they could be set to an object. Thanks @Danny Dainton!
I've tested this by logging the key values like so:
var env = pm.environment.toObject();

for (var k in env){
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(env,k)) {
         console.log("Key is " + k + ", value is" + env[k]); 
    }
}

Comment: You could probably add an `if`statement to only clear the ones that start with `tmp` etc. Worth just messing about with it to find what works. All API ref info is here https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference

Comment: @cutlass I've also added an easier method of logging them to the console.